# Why do I keep getting a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: JVM Heap Space" or "GC overhead limit exceeded" while running the Stanford NER classifier?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a model using Stanford NER(https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml). I have followed [this](http://douglasduhaime.com/blog/training-the-stanford-ner-classifier-to-study-literary-history) blog post to create a dataset and train. When I have a small dataset, it runs just fine but it gives a pretty bad accuracy. When I try to scale up the data and run the command:

> java -cp stanford-ner-3.7.0.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop propforclassifierone.prop

I am getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.AnnotationLookup$KeyLookup.values(AnnotationLookup.java:18)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.AnnotationLookup.toCoreKey(AnnotationLookup.java:146)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.initFromStrings(CoreLabel.java:175)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.(CoreLabel.java:136)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter$ColumnDocParser.apply(ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.java:88)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter$ColumnDocParser.apply(ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.java:64)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.parseString(DelimitRegExIterator.java:67)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.setNext(DelimitRegExIterator.java:60)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.(DelimitRegExIterator.java:54)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator$DelimitRegExIteratorFactory.getIterator(DelimitRegExIterator.java:122)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.getIterator(ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.java:58)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.setNextObject(ObjectBank.java:436)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.next(ObjectBank.java:460)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ObjectBankWrapper$WrappedIterator.hasNext(ObjectBankWrapper.java:61)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.train(CRFClassifier.java:1585)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:773)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:744)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3034)

As I researched about it online, I found out that using -Xmx parameters and also -XX parameter with my java -cp command can help provide the needed heap space during execution time. But still, I got the same error. Does the Stanford CRF NER not support huge data? The new command that I used is:

> java -Xms2g -Xmx50g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -cp stanford-ner-3.7.0.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop propforclassifierone.prop --multiThreadGrad 8

After this, I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space

My prop file is just the same as described in the blog(link above). I even tried tweaking the -Xms parameters with no luck.

I am running all this on a server with 300GB RAM! I can't understand how is it possible that it gives a heap error with this amount of RAM.
I am using stanford-ner-3.7.0 which I understand is the latest one.

*I appreciate your time, thank you so much. If there is anything you couldn't understand, write it down in the comments and I'll try my best to sort it out for you!*

**UPDATE:** If I train the same amount of dataset with only one or two labels, then I am successfully able to do that. So I'll be creating a pipeline of various models and pass my test data through all of them. Any advice on this approach would be more than welcome :)

Comment: If i remember well java will self-limit it's heap space and will not take the full space availlable unless you tell it to do so. And depending on the OS configuration, a single process might not have access to the whole 300GB.

Comment: Do you think there's a workaround to it through command line @litelite ?

Comment: When you run such java command watch for growing of memory usage and see what is the maximum it achieved. It is possible for any program to take too much resources, don't assume it shouldn't.

Comment: How many NER classes do you have?  If you have too many classes you can generate large RAM requirements.

Comment: I have, in total, 7 classes @StanfordNLPHelp ! But that's the thing, if it generates large RAM requirements, I can suppliment that but can't seem to figure out how!

Comment: You say you have 300GB, but you're only giving it 50GB.

Comment: @the8472 Tried using -Xmx290g as well but that didn't work either. Seems like some other issue only :(

Comment: What do you think, how much memory consumption should be reasonable for your task? Or, in other words, what backs your assumption that consuming 300G is too much?

Comment: Hi @Holger, my training file is around 2GB so I assume it shouldn't take 300G. That's just preposterous!

Comment: Well, if you consider the memory consumption unnatural, you can take a heap dump and analyze it. But it requires an idea of what a natural heap looks like for this task, to identify the aberrant artifacts.

Comment: How many training sentences do you have?  The NER system we have used training data that is 3.1 MB.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp The number of sentences in my training file comes at around 10 million which makes a 1.5-2GB file!

Comment: Well I haven't looked at the memory requirements during training that closely, but we train our system on something like 20,000 sentences.  So that is probably your issue.  We have never attempted to use our training code on millions of sentences.

Comment: Hi @StanfordNLPHelp, thank you so much for the assistance. Do you think a good model can be achieved by using a training set of only 20K sentences?
Anyway, if I train one label with the same amount of data I am able to do that without the JVM throwing this error.

Comment: @MadhavSharma did u find any solutoin for this problem? got the same..

Comment: Hi @MpizosDimitris 
I did manage to find a solution. The only problem was that the Stanford NER is not able to handle a large amount of data with more than 3 labels. I would suggest you train the model with the same amount of data but with only one label and see if it's working. Similarly, train models like this and you'll have multiple models instead of one. You can then run them on a NLP server and use it.  Let me know if you are able to solve your issue. Check UPDATE on my question above to see how I worked it around! Cheers